# find image in div and place in an other div on top of page

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs. One at the top of the page and one all the down of the page.

like so:

```
<div class="collectionHeader">
 <h1>Some title</h1>
 <div class="image"></div>
</div>

...... a lot of html code ..........

<div class="text">                  
  <img width="558" height="100" src="stoelen.jpg" />
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet etc....
</div>
```

What i try to achieve is to select the image in the div called "text" and place this image in the div called "image" on the top of the page.

I really don't have a clue on how to achieve this!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.appendTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) this will insert the element at the end of the target or you can also use [**prependTo()**](https://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) to insert it as the first element

```
$(".text").find("img").appendTo(".image")
```

Comment: You mean `.image` surely?

Comment: @Eduardo Quintana: I have to keep away from the coffee... #$%$!$@

Comment: LOL, why? sometimes is needed :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**:

```
$(".text img").appendTo(".image");
```

or **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```
$('.image').append($(".text img"));
```